# Android recyclerview not setting the items on first attempt

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

In my activity, I have a `recyclerview` which displays the images in grid. The activity shows images from a collection.When the collection already contains images and I open the activity, the `recyclerview` sets all the images properly. My problem is when the I select image from gallery or camera and in `onActivityResult()` method try to set that to `recyclerview` using **`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`** method, the `recyclerview` is not getting updated if the collection is empty. And the same code is working fine if the collection contains images and I try to upload new image to it. Basically, I'm selecting images from gallery and then in `onActivityResult()` method I'm setting the selected images to the `recyclerview` and the images are uploaded in the background to the server.

My Adapter code

```
private void setAdapter(final List<AlbumImagesBean> albumImages) {
adapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter<AlbumImagesBean>(R.layout.album_images_grid_adapter_item) {
    @Override
    protected void setupViewHolder(MAWRecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position, final AlbumImagesBean item) {
        mawViewHolder = holder;
        ProgressBar progressBar = holder.getView(R.id.progressBar);
         ((ImageView) holder.getView(R.id.ivImage)).setImageURI(Uri.parse(item.getImage()));
          }
        };

        adapter.init(albumImages, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridRecyclerViewDivider(5, 3));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
```

`onActivityResult()` method code

```
    ArrayList<String> images = data.getStringArrayListExtra(UIConstants.INTENT_EXTRA_IMAGES);
    if (isNotNull(images)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
            String path = images.get(i);
            newRequests = new ArrayList<>();
            AddFileRequest request = new AddFileRequest();
            request.setUserId(userCache.getUserData().getUserId());
            request.setType(UIConstants.UPLOAD_FILE_TYPE_ALBUM);
            request.setTypeId(albumBean.getAlbumId());
            request.setTitle(EMPTY);
            request.setFile(path);
            AlbumImagesBean imageBean = new AlbumImagesBean(path);
            imageBean.setUploading(true);
            imageBean.setLocalImage(true);
            adapter.addItem(imageBean);
            albumImages = adapter.getData();
            newRequests.add(request);
            uploadAttachmentAPICall();
          }
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

I'm not able to understand what's going wrong.Thanks for any help.

```
public void addItem(T t) {
    createDataIfNotExits();
    data.add(t);
    notifyChanges();
}

public List<T> getData() {
    return data;
}

private void createDataIfNotExits() {
    if (data == null) {
        data = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

public void init(List<T> data, boolean isPagination) {
    MAWRecyclerAdapter.isPagination = isPagination;
    if (data == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("data can not be null");
    }
    this.data = data;
    if (isPagination) {
        this.data.add(null);
    }
    notifyChanges();
}
```

Also I have called `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged( );` in the response of API call , but still the image is not added to recyclerview.

Comment: attach code for these methods. adapter.addItem(imageBean),adapter.getData();

Comment: keep your `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` below for loop

Comment: @IncipientInfo tried that , but still it doesn't refreshes the recyclerview

Comment: Did you checked the size of adapter after adding the first item?

Comment: yes , the adapter contains the added item

Comment: public void addItem(T t) {
    createDataIfNotExits();
    data.add(t);
notifyDataSetChanged();
}

Also remove the notifyDataSetChanged();
 from loop.

Comment: @Neha as you told your data is loaded afterwards, that is because your recyclerview adapter is already set and you are setting that again but not assigning that to recyclerview. Instead of `setAdapter(albumImages);` in your if condition just call ` adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: and yes as @kundankamal told remove `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` from the loop and keep it outside.

Comment: Updated my code and tried it , it is not working

Comment: please try with this : add `albumImages = new ArrayList<>();` above ` adapter.init(albumImages, false);` and remove `createDataIfNotExits();` from method `addItem(T t)`

Comment: actually `adapter.init(albumImages,false);` is inside the setAdapter() method ,which takes albumImages list as input parameter. I forgot to add it while sharing the code, sorry for that.

Comment: okay, but my concern is just that initialise it before setting the adapter and avoid initialising that in method addItem(T t)

Comment: the arraylist is not initialized everytime an item is added ,it is initialized only if list is empty.I'll try your suggestion and let you know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196958/discussion-between-incipientinfo-and-neha).

Comment: Is this issue fixed? If not can you add code for adapter.init() method?